# Realm.getInstance(context) not working anymore after Migration

Tags: android, realm

After doing a migration, i cant use the `Realm.getInstance(context);` anymore

Error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot have different schema versions if used to open the same file. 1 vs. 0`

i saw that i must use the created configs previosly to do the migration

```
RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
```

now i must create the config1 again everywhere i use the

`Realm.getInstance(context);`

i used to add this for each method to avoid any kind of null

```
public List<CustomClass> getAll() {
realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
....
}



public CustomClass getOneById(int id) {
realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
...
}
```

and sometimes outside the DAO class where i dynamically change the database i use this:

```
Realm.getInstance(context).beginTransaction();

change object

Realm.getInstance(context).commitTransaction();
```

now i must create this CONFIG1 (RealmConfiguration) EVERYWHERE? or is there any other approach?

i tried adding to the MainClass this         `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(CONFIG1);` but no success =/

i was wrong for checking or avoiding null on realm object calling the getInstance for each method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use     `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(CONFIG1);` 
 to set default configuration :

and use     `Realm.getDefaultInstance();` to get default realm instance.

Comment: worked, funny was that the first time its doesnt worked, thank youuuu

Comment: This answer makes sense, but what if the existing codebase makes use of Realm.getInstance(context) calls due to operating in background threads?